# what is the code for the flip corner on freelancer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Chrome now and got interested in checking the code for the flip corner on freelancer.com BUT I couldn't find any html related to the corner picture or any CSS except the `<a>` tag which has no embeded CSS for the background image!!!

Any thoughts? I think the big question, how could you hide your code like they did?

Answer (score 2):

It's a background image attached to the body:

```
.ns-sticker {
    background: url(/img/folded-banner.png?v=82d6815ae6517ce07aaa66ad4a678f77&m=1) top right no-repeat;
}
```

The `<a>` tag is just a clickable area:

```
#box-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 130px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I wouldn't do it this way. Just give the `<a>` element a background image and absolutely position it.

Comment: Agreed, it seems over complicated to set a background image to the body and position a separate anchor element above it.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't hiding their code.

http://cdn3.f-cdn.com/img/folded-banner.png?v=82d6815ae6517ce07aaa66ad4a678f77&m=1